# How can I bulkify this? Can't figure out how to map date across

Tags: apex, trigger

As the title says, I have tried to bulkify this but can't seem to figure out how to map the date across properly. What I have posted below is the non bulkified version and not my attempt at bulkifying it.

```
public static void updateSOACloseDate(Opportunity[] opps){
    List<Opportunity> dpilist = new List<Opportunity>();
    Date dtoday = System.today() - 30;
        for(Opportunity opp : opps){
            for(Opportunity relatedDPI : [Select Id from Opportunity where AccountId =: opp.AccountID AND CreatedDate > :dtoday 
                                            AND RecordTypeID in (Select Id from RecordType where Name = 'Realty Sales')]){
                Date dclosedate = opp.CloseDate;
                Datetime dtclosedate = datetime.newInstance(dclosedate.year(), dclosedate.month(), dclosedate.day());
                relatedDPI.SOA_Appointment_Date__c = dtclosedate;
                dpilist.add(relatedDPI);
            }
        }     
    update dpilist;

}
```

Comment: Is this suppose to update all related opportunities created in the past thirty days on the same account as a given opportunity? That's not clear from this code, because it doesn't compile as is.

Comment: @Michael from where are you getting 'accId' , that is used in query ?

Comment: Sorry I have fixed where AccountId is coming from

Comment: @sdfx the related opportunities it is updating is of a different record type.

Comment: @Michael your last edit makes more sense. I updated my answer below according to that, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use maps:

```
public static void updateSOACloseDate(Opportunity[] opps){
    List<Id> accIds = new List<Id>();
    Map<String, List<Opportunity>> dpiMap = Map<String, List<Opportunity>>();
    Map<String, Opportunity> dpisToUpd = new Map<String, Opportunity>()
    Date dtoday = System.today() - 30;
    for (Opportunity opp : opps) {
        accIds.add(opp.AccountID);
    }
    for (Opportunity relatedDPI : [SELECT Id, SOA_Appointment_Date__c FROM Opportunity 
                                   WHERE AccountId IN :accIds AND 
                                         CreatedDate > :dtoday AND 
                                         RecordTypeID in (Select Id from RecordType where Name = 'Realty Sales')]) {
        if (!dpiMap.containsKey(relatedDPI.AccountId)) {
            dpiMap.put(relatedDPI.AccountId, new List<Opportunity>());
        }
        dpiMap.get(relatedDPI.AccountId).add(relatedDPI);
    }
    for (Opportunity opp : opps){
        if (dpiMap.containsKey(opp.AccountID)) {
            for (Opportunity relatedDPI : dpiMap.get(opp.AccountID)) {
                Date dclosedate = opp.CloseDate;
                Datetime dtclosedate = datetime.newInstance(dclosedate.year(), dclosedate.month(), dclosedate.day());
                relatedDPI.SOA_Appointment_Date__c = dtclosedate;
                dpisToUpd.put(relatedDPI.Id, relatedDPI);
            }
        }
    }     
    update dpisToUpd.values();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joca, this was close to what my attempt at it was! I just wasn't sure about how to get the Ids into the map and them iterate back over it when there isn't a lookup field to put into the map for the queried records.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure,where is that accId coming from ?! If this list(I see you used 'IN: ' ) is prepared outside the for loop, Try below code -

```
public static void updateSOACloseDate(Opportunity[] opps){
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult d = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity; 
rtMapByName = d.getRecordTypeInfosByName();      
rtREALTYSALE = rtMapByName.get('Realty Sales');
List<Opportunity> dpilist = new List<Opportunity>();
Date dtoday = System.today() - 30;
List<Opportunity> dbList = [SELECT Id 
                             FROM   Opportunity 
                             WHERE  AccountId    IN: accId 
                             AND    CreatedDate  > : dtoday 
                             AND    RecordTypeID IN (SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Realty Sales')];

    for(Opportunity opp : opps){
        for(Opportunity relatedDPI : dbList){
            Date dclosedate = opp.CloseDate;
            Datetime dtclosedate = datetime.newInstance(dclosedate.year(), dclosedate.month(), dclosedate.day());
            relatedDPI.SOA_Appointment_Date__c = dtclosedate;
            dpilist.add(relatedDPI);
        }
    }     
update dpilist;
}
```